# Finding CSS that generates textual content?

Tags: css, localization, internationalization

I'm working on a project that is internationalizing/localizing a web application.  I am researching what CSS constructs can insert or generate textual content.

I am aware of the [::before and ::after pseudo-elements](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#gen-content) and based on the MDN [content CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/content) documentation, I think this is all.  Are there other constructs I should be aware of?

```
element:after  { style properties }  /* CSS2 syntax */

element::after { style properties }  /* CSS3 syntax */
```

Also, I do know I have some images (and image sprites) with English words that are used in `background-url` constructs.

**Edit:** It wasn't clear from my original question, but I'm refactoring out hard-coded language strings throughout the application, and trying to find where in CSS this could exist.  I feel confident in server and client generated views, less so on images with textual content, and unclear what CSS constructs might contain English displayable text.

Comment: What exactly is the question? If there is another way to add content via CSS?

Answer (score 2):

What you have mentioned in the question is what CSS has to generate textual content, if we don’t count the [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/), a Working Draft from 2003. The draft makes the `content` property apply to normal elements as well, so that you could *replace* element content, instead of just adding content (so you could have `.greeting:lang(en) { content: "Hello world!" } .greeting:lang(es) { content: "¡Hola, mundo!" }`). But this has been implemented only in Opera.

A more realistic approach to using CSS for localization is to place all the language variants inside the HTML document as different elements, with `lang` attributes, and choose between them in CSS, e.g.

```
<style>
[lang=es] [lang=en], 
[lang=en] [lang=es] 
  { display: none; }
</style>
<body lang=en>
<p lang=en>Hello world!</p>
<p lang=es>¡Hola, mundo!</p>
```

Then you could change the language of the visible text simply by changing the value of the `lang` attribute on the `body` element.

There are essential flaws with this approach, so I described this basically to show that **CSS is not the answer to localization.** This is the best you can get that way, and it’s not nice. For a web page, you don’t want to give search engines a page containing such a mix of languages in content. For an application, JavaScript is a much better tool.

On the other hand, localization poses some some specific [challenges](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/multicss.html) to styling, such as texts running out of their boxes since some translation is two times longer than the visual designer expected.